# Putting line-breaks in the (Mountain) Lion lock screen message

Tags: macos, user-account

On Mountain Lion, in the [Security & Privacy] pane of System Preferences, you can enter a lock screen message that gets displayed on the login/lock screen.
Sometimes, you might want to put a line break or a paragraph gap there. You might think that you could do this, hence the large text box, however you can't - even if it looks like you can. <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> doesn't enter a line break. I know it's possible, because iCloud does it when you lock your computer with Find My iPhone.
Is it actually possible to enter line breaks in your lock screen message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually is. You can't do it directly from System Preferences - you can do it using TextEdit. Just type your lock screen message into TextEdit and copy-paste into the text box in System Preferences. If you use more than three lines, then a scroll bar appears and everything looks all buggy and ugly. Three lines or less works perfectly - in fact, I have three lines right now! (Third line blacked out as it contains my email address)

[image: The lock screen sheet, showing a multi-line message.]

Comment: This isn't entirely true. Pat's answer is correct in saying that you can add a line directly in System Preferences, but they got the key combination wrong. I'll submit an edit.

Answer (score 5):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> for a new line (or <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, which seems to work as well).